# ImportError: cannot import name 'Settings' from 'pandas_profiling.config' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_profiling/config.py)

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, data-analysis

I'm trying to  import pandas profiling on goggle colab.

```
!pip install https://github.com/ydataai/pandas-profiling/archive/master.zip
```

after succesfully installing pandas-profiling

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

when I try to import ProfileReport

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-c03a24be5f20> in <module>()
      1 import numpy as np
      2 import pandas as pd
----> 3 from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_profiling/profile_report.py in <module>()
     11 from visions import VisionsTypeset
     12 
---> 13 from pandas_profiling.config import Config, Settings
     14 from pandas_profiling.expectations_report import ExpectationsReport
     15 from pandas_profiling.model.alerts import AlertType

ImportError: cannot import name 'Settings' from 'pandas_profiling.config' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas_profiling/config.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

i have already tried to solve this by installing latest version of pandas-profiling and installing visions.

Comment: Have you try to use !apt as said on the error message?

Comment: @GregoryOliveira yes i've tried that. !apt was saying package not found. but thankfully `!pip install pandas-profiling==2.7.1` solved it for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
!pip install pandas-profiling==2.7.1
```

solved it for me. You might need to use:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install -U pandas-profiling[notebook]
!jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
```

and

`!pip install ipywidgets`

also if you are using a notebook.